# Need help attaching a number from one array to its corresponding string in another array

Tags: java

For the code below, I am trying to input a n number of names name and marks. The code then reads the inputs and spits out the avg of marks and the highest and lowest marks names.

I have had some issues linking the max and min marks name to the marks themselves. I setup two arrays but am not sure how to track the position of the max and min mark to then link them to their corresponding name.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Marks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //It all goes in here

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many students are there? ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        String[] names = new String[n];
        int[] marks = new int[n];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter name of student " + (i + 1) +": " );
            names[i] = sc.next();
        
            System.out.print("Enter mark " + (i + 1) +": ");
            marks[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
            sum += marks[i];
        }
        float average = (sum / marks.length);
        System.out.println("The average mark is: " + average);
        
        int maxMark = marks[0];
        for (int i = 0;i < n; i++){
            if (marks[i] > maxMark){
                maxMark = marks[i];
            }
        }

        int minMark = marks[0];
        for (int i = 0;i < n; i++){
            if (marks[i] < minMark){
                minMark = marks[i];
            }
        }
    
        System.out.println("The best student is " + maxMark);
        System.out.println("The worst student is " + minMark);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, do you mean `Java` for your language instead of `javascript`?

Comment: please change your tag to **java** instead of  **javascript**

Comment: You are using arrays. arrays are indexed. Since you are storing the names and their marks with the same index, i in the for loop, you can keep track of which name/mark using index. You can keep current, max, min indices variables and update them as and when required. I hope I understood the requirement correctly but if not, please clarify your need and use scenario for better answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing that. For example, you can store index of the student along with max/min mark:

```java
int minMark = marks[0];
int minMarkIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0;i < n; i++){
    if (marks[i] < minMark){
        minMark = marks[i];
        minMarkIndex = i;
}
```

And then use this index to display student's name:

```
System.out.println("The student with minimal mark is ", names[minMarkIndex]);
```

More advanced approach is to create class `Student`. One of classes use cases is to encapsulate certain data. In this case, we'll encapsulate student's name and student's mark:

```java
class Student {
    public String name;
    public int mark;

    Student(String name, int mark) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mark = mark;
    }
}
```

Note that there are a lot of conventions in terms of class definition, and class fields are seldom marked `public`, but it's okay for explanation.

And then, you store user input in instances of `Student` class. These instances are then used to retrieve data that is stored in them:

```java
Student[] students = new Student[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    students[i] = new Student(names[i], marks[i]);
}

Student studentWithLowestMark = students[0], studentWithHighestMark = students[0];

for (Student student : students) { // iterates through students array, student == students[i]
   if(student.mark < studentWithLowestMark.mark) {
       studentWithLowestMark = student;
   } 
   if(student.mark > studentWithHighestMark.mark) {
       studentWithHighestMark = student;
   }
} 


System.out.println("Student with highest mark " + studentWithHighestMark.mark 
    + " is " studentWithHighestMark.name);

System.out.println("Student with lowest mark " + studentWithLowestMark.mark 
    + " is " studentWithLowestMark.name);
```

Opposite to first approach, this approach couples student's name and mark, so you can't by mistake use name of one student and mark of other:

```java
// First approach allows this
System.out.println("Student " + names[0] + " has mark " + marks[1]) // Incorrect!

// Second approach simplifies the usage and preserves this type of error
System.out.println("Student " + student.name + " has mark " + student.mark);
```